# Option to merge two examples (or delete one) in documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation-examples

Why isn't there an option to merge two examples or delete one altogether?

Currently we have:
[image: I think this example is..]

Why not give an option to mark duplicate or cast delete vote?

Example:

1. [Initialize serial device example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/5744/python-serial-communication-pyserial/20310/initialize-serial-device#t=201611201012278493724)
2. [Read from serial port example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/5744/python-serial-communication-pyserial/20311/read-from-serial-port#t=201611201012278493724)

Here the first one can easily be merged with the second, as seen in this proposed change: [change proposed for the second example to add details from first one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/111247?filter-tags=python)

By adding a delete vote, we can remove unwanted/unnecessary examples.

If there was an option to delete, it would have been easier to clean such unnecessary examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already *can* delete examples. Just click the trash can icon at the top-right in edit mode.
You already *can* merge examples. Delete one and copy/paste its contents into the other.

Comment: Delete how? There is only `edit`, `share` and `request improvement` option.

Comment: @AniMenon you have to be in edit mode.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I hadn't noticed it earlier. But I think it should be available in the document panel rather than in edit mode.

Comment: Why did you have to remove [feature-request]? I was going for that tag badge :(

Comment: It isn't a request anymore as you said the feature already exists! You could edit the question to say "add delete button in the documentation panel" and add `feature request` tag if you would like.

Comment: @AniMenon no, it is still a feature request, because it is still a request to add or change something in the SE/SO engine. The fact that the feature you were requesting already existed doesn't change that; as an example, see [this question](/q/337860/6388243) of mine.